# Permutation Importance is 0 with high accuracy

Tags: feature-selection, logistic-regression

I am using sklearn's `permutation_importance` for feature selection, and all my features return score decreases of 0, even though my model accuracy is 0.96.

I have tried the permutation with other metrics, and only the `roc_auc_score` actually returns non-zero value, but any other metrics returns zeros for all features. I guess I am confused as to how this is possible, as the feature importance with the following code (should) output the drop in accuracy when we shuffle the values of the different variables.

```
model = LogisticRegression().fit(X, y)

permutation_score = permutation_importance(model, X, y, scoring = 'accuracy', n_repeats=10)
```

On another note, I ran a correlation test between my explanatory variables, and none of the variables seemed too highly correlated.